# Centering an IMG and Text in Skeleton Boilerplate

Tags: html, css

Trying to center the text and also an img in the Skeleton Boilerplate. I have the text centered in the page but not in the div... I also want the image banner to be centered as well.

Thank you in advance for any help or direction or tips. Landing page is at http://www.forensicfilesnow.com

The code for Skeleton can be found here as well (http://getskeleton.com). Didn't want to copy the entire CSS page cause it would be really long and there's a lot of styling that isn't necessary and I'm not even using.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <!-- Basic Page Needs
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Forensic Files Now</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <!-- Mobile Specific Metas
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- FONT
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Special+Elite:400,300,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  <!-- CSS
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skeleton.css">

  <!-- Favicon
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">

</head>
<body>

  <!-- Primary Page Layout
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <div class="container" style="text-align:center;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="one-third column">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="one-third column" style="margin-top: 5%">
        <h4>Coming Soon...</h4>
        <p>Your new home for Forensic Files fans, backstories, and questions and more.</p>
        <img id="ffnowbanner" src="images/forensicfilesnow-banner.png" alt="Trulli" width="450" height="600">
      </div>
      <div class="one-third column">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  </div>

<!-- End Document
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the flex-box, for example you can set

```css
    .row {  
       display: flex;
       flex-direction: column;
       align-content: center;
       justify-content: center;
       align-items: center;
    }
```

and

```css
      @media (min-width: 550px){
       .one-third.column {
           width: auto;
       } 
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's your main div, that needs to be centered...

```
    <div class="one-third column" style="margin-top: 5%">
        <h4>Coming Soon...</h4>
        <p>Your new home for Forensic Files fans, backstories, and questions and more.</p>
        <img id="ffnowbanner" src="images/forensicfilesnow-banner.png" alt="Trulli" width="450" height="600">
    </div>
```

You can edit it's style and play with position and margins (just exapmle, you can change numbers):

```
<div class="one-third column" style="margin-top: 5%; position: absolute; margin-left: 40%; width: 20%">
```

— position: absolute; makes your div "independent" from the other elements, while using margin.

— Margin-left: 40%; makes it to set field from the left side of the screen 40%...

— It's own width: 20%, and the remaining 40% - will stay to the right side.

You also can set margin-left: 123px; and play with pixels. But it will work on your screen, and can fail on the other screen, which could be larger or smaller. Percents work better.